# Build ElasticSearch Query using org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch java library

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I want to build the following ES query using BoolQueryBuilders and Aggregator, but I am unable to do that.

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": {
        "bool": {
          "filter": [
            {
              "terms": {
                "country": [
                  "France",
                  "China"
                ]
              }
            },
            {
              "term": {
                "lang": "en"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "group_by_country": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "country",
        "size": 0
      },
      "aggs": {
        "top_hits_country": {
          "top_hits": {
            "size": 1
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I am able to build this query without the aggregator, in the following manner -

```
BoolQueryBuilder innerEntityQueryBuilder = new BoolQueryBuilder();
        
BoolQueryBuilder queryBuilder = new BoolQueryBuilder()
                    .filter(QueryBuilders.termsQuery("country", countries)) 
                    .filter(QueryBuilders.termQuery("lang", "en")); 
innerEntityQueryBuilder.should(queryBuilder);
```

How do I add the aggregate part as well?

Answer (score 1):

like this：

```
SearchRequest searchRequest = new SearchRequest();
searchRequest.indices("index1");

SearchSourceBuilder searchSourceBuilder = new SearchSourceBuilder();
searchSourceBuilder.size(0);

BoolQueryBuilder bqb = new BoolQueryBuilder()
        .filter(QueryBuilders.termsQuery("country", "France","China"))
        .filter(QueryBuilders.termQuery("lang", "en"));
searchSourceBuilder.query(bqb);


TermsAggregationBuilder group = AggregationBuilders
        .terms("group_by_country").field("country")
        .size(0);
TopHitsAggregationBuilder topHit = AggregationBuilders.topHits("top_hits_country").size(1);
group.subAggregation(topHit);

searchSourceBuilder.aggregation(group);

searchRequest.source(searchSourceBuilder);
```